# Dynamic Drop down list with submit button - test.php?index=$value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want a way to store the option selected from the user in a variable.

thanks

```
$results = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM id
 WHERE test  = '".$pull ."';");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='id'>";
   while($table = $results->fetchArray()){
      $table_= $table['id'] -1;
      $b = "1" . $table_ ;
      echo '<option value="'.$table_.'">'.$table_.'</option>';
   }
echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: didn't get you on this line:- `When the user select an option. I want the selected to be in value. echo "`

Comment: What do you expect the result of `$table_ == $table_` to be on every iteration?

Comment: I mean, when the user click on one of the drop menu option. I want the selected option to be in a variable ($value), so when I can use that variable and do test.php?index=$value

Comment: $table_ == $table_ will always be the same actually. 
echo '<option value="'.$table_.'">'.$table_.'</option>';
I had this at first.

Comment: edited the main topic

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript for your task.
First, you have to find in DOM your selection, something like: 
`const yourSelector = document.querySelector('<your_selector>');
     //and perhaps we need to check form
     const form = querySelector('form');`
Than, when user clicks on Submit button you have to prevent event, like this:
    `const submitButton = document.querySelector('#<id_of_button>');
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selectedValue = yourSelector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value
    form.action = 'test.php?index=${selectedValue}'}`

And than submit form. Please, notice that here we use ES6 statements with symbol on tylda ` (not single quote), when setting form.action.